# Saving multiple panda dataframes in one excel worksheet out of a for loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

As a follow up on my experiments, I need to increase the reagents I want to test. I was able to create a for loop which takes the concentration and amounts of a excel file, and creates pivot tables/data frames which show me the concentration as Index/Header and the amounts to pipet in the cells. However, I struggle at saving them into a single worksheet since they are multiple dataframes.
My current approach results in an `TypeError: unhashable type: 'DataFrame'`

Here is the starting data:

| 6-BAP_Conc | TDZ_Conc | Picloram_Conc | 2,4D_Conc | Dicamba_Conc | 6-BAP_Vol | TDZ_Vol Picloram_Vol | 2,4D_Vol | Dicamba_Vol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 0.0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 0.1 | 0.5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.337875 | 0.33039 | 0.14487 | 0.132624 |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 3.37875 | 0.6607799999999999 | 1.4487 | 1.32624 |
| 5.0 | 2.0 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 16.89375 | 1.32156 | 2.8974 | 2.65248 |

[image: Starting Data from excel file]

So here is my approach:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product


df = pd.read_excel("BlueTest.xlsx")


with pd.ExcelWriter('test3.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Result')
    writer.sheets['Result'] = worksheet

COLUMN = 0
row = 0


for x in ["6-BAP", "TDZ"]:
    for y in ["Picloram","2,4D","Dicamba"]:
        df1 = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith(x)]
        df2 = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith(y)]
        my_product = list(product(df1[f"{x}_Vol"], df2[f"{y}_Vol"]))
        my_product_str = [str(a) + "uL" for a in my_product]
        my_product_str_np = np.array(my_product_str)
        my_product_str_np = my_product_str_np.reshape(len(df1), len(df2))
        dfn = pd.DataFrame(my_product_str_np, index=df1[f"{x}_Conc.1"], columns=df2[f"{y}_Conc"])
        worksheet.write_string(row,COLUMN,dfn)
        row += 1
        dfn.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Results", startrow= row, startcol=COLUMN)
        row += dfn.shape[0]+2
```

I would really appreciate some help with this, since im struggeling hard with these kind of things and python.

Comment: From what I see you want all results in one sheet. The easiest approach is to create an empty dataframe and append to it the result after each iteration. Then put the end dataframe to_excel and it will work. If you put the input data not as a picture but something i can copy/paste I can help. You can try df.to_clipboard for that https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html

Comment: Thanks, Atanas for letting me know that, I made the data now into a table so it should be copyable. I will try out your approach with appending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

#reading the table you pasted 
df = pd.read_clipboard()


#the function that will append new data or create an empty dataframe
def append_df(df_data, df_result):
    if df_data.empty:
        df_data  = df_result
    else:
        df_data = df_data.append(other=df_result, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

    return df_data

#seems you have and error in the table so here I am sorting it out (error when comparing table to the picture(TDZ_Vol Picloram_Vol are in one column and not separate))
df=df.rename(columns={"TDZ_Vol Picloram_Vol":"TDZ_Vol"})
df = df.assign(Picloram_Vol=[0,0.14487,0.14487,2.8974])
df=df.rename(columns={"col_name":"Picloram_Vol"})


df_data=pd.DataFrame()
for x in ["6-BAP", "TDZ"]:
    for y in ["Picloram","2,4D","Dicamba"]:
        df1 = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith(x)]
        df2 = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith(y)]
        my_product = list(product(df1[f"{x}_Vol"], df2[f"{y}_Vol"]))
        my_product_str = [str(a) + "uL" for a in my_product]
        my_product_str_np = np.array(my_product_str)
        my_product_str_np = my_product_str_np.reshape(len(df1), len(df2))
        
        dfn = pd.DataFrame(my_product_str_np, index=df1[f"{x}_Conc"], columns=df2[f"{y}_Conc"])
        
        #reseting index as concentrations can be different
        dfn=dfn.reset_index()
        #reating a row with your column names (as concetrations can be different )
        dfn=pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([dfn.columns, dfn]))
        
        #using the function top append data
        df_data = append_df(df_data, dfn)
```

Comment: Ah wow thats great, I tried yesterday also some other approaches but this is really elegant. Thank you very much!